# Replace old StackNavigator with a new one, React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to replace an StackNavigator that should not be used when the user has gone passed the "LogIn" stage. But i can't figure out how to do this, I have tried the reset function but can't get that to work as wanted.

How do I replace an old StackNavigator with a new and use that one? As shown in the example below the system starts with one stack and that stack should not be used after the button has been pressed.

the index code as an example:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import App from './App';

class StackNavigatorStuff extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome',
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Welcome to this app
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Some login functions to become
        </Text>
        <Button title = 'Temp Login Function' onPress={() => /*Here should the  stack be replaced with App.MainStackNav*/})}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})
  ]
});

const StackNavigatorLab = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: StackNavigatorStuff },
  //More to be
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('StackNavigatorLab', () => StackNavigatorLab);
```

And the App.MainStackNav

```
 const StackNavigatorLab = StackNavigator({

  Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
  Chat: { screen: ChatNavigator },
  NavigationList: { screen: MyNotificationsScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation can only happen within a defined router, so you should have a navigator wrapping the screens you want to switch between.

In you `index` file's `StackNavigatorLab`, add `App.MainStackNav` to it as a route. i.e.

```
const StackNavigatorLab = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: StackNavigatorStuff },
  Main: { screen: App.MainStackNav },
...
});
```

And then your reset action would look like

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Main' })
  ]
});
```

Use `navigation.dispatch` to dispatch this reset action after successful login.

If you want to separate two sets of StackNavigation screens, you can have an overall `StackNavigator` as a root that just wraps the `Login` set of screens and the `Main` set of screen.